# Converting uppercase to lowercase using XSLT 1.0 however first character should remain caps

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an requirement in which I need to convert from uppercase to lowercase. However the first letter should remain uppercase.

Input:`<LineStatus>DELETED</LineStatus>`

Expected Output: `<LineStatus>Deleted</LineStatus>`

Below is the code

```
`<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
  <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(DELETED, $smallcase, $uppercase)" />
</xsl:template>`
```

This will give the output as `deleted`

I have tried something like `<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(DELETED,1,1), $smallcase, $uppercase)" />` but it gave me output `d`

Can anyone please advise?

**UPDATE**

I have created a template in which I am doing this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<<xsl:variable name="LineStatus"  select="//OrderResponse/OrderResponseBody/OrderResponseDetails/OrderResponseProductLineItem/LineStatus/text()"/>
<xsl:variable name="change"><xsl:value-of select="substring($LineStatus, 1, 1)"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="RSRIden" select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='OrderResponse']/*[local-name()='OrderResponseBody']/*[local-name()='OrderResponseDetails']/*[local-name()='OrderResponseProductLineItem']/*[local-name()='SpecialInstructions' and @*[local-name()='InstructionType' and normalize-space(.) = 'PostingInstructions']]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RSRDescri" select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='OrderResponse']/*[local-name()='OrderResponseBody']/*[local-name()='OrderResponseDetails']/*[local-name()='OrderResponseProductLineItem']/*[local-name()='SpecialInstructions' and @*[local-name()='InstructionType' and normalize-space(.) = 'ShipperInstructions']]"/>
    <xsl:template name="Reject-Status">
        <ResponseStatus>
            <ResponseStatusReasonIdentifier Agency="ResponseCode">
                <xsl:value-of select="$RSRIden"/>
            </ResponseStatusReasonIdentifier>
            <ResponseStatusReasonDescription>
                <xsl:value-of select="$RSRDescri"/>
            </ResponseStatusReasonDescription>
        </ResponseStatus>

            <!--<LineStatus><xsl:value-of select="translate($change,$uppercase,$smallcase)" /></LineStatus>-->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Changed to this and worked**

```
<LineStatus><xsl:value-of select="substring($LineStatus, 1, 1)"/><xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($LineStatus,2),$uppercase,$smallcase)" /></LineStatus>
```

Comment: You should declare the `soap` namespace in your XSL document, so that instead of `/*[local-name()='Envelope']` you could simply use `/soap:Envelope`.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you I will update the XSL. But does that affect what I am  trying to achieve?

Comment: No, that's why I wrote it as a comment. It will make your XPath quite a bit more manageable. Michael's answer below has your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and mean while I will test try to work with Michael solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
<xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(LineStatus, 1, 1)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(LineStatus, 2), $uppercase, $lowercase)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael and Tomalak your solutions is working. I just had to tweak my code and it worked. The only change I did was i declared as $LineStatus and added both <xsl:value-of in the element